# Network Error when trying to connect custom API to react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a network error in Expo React with custom built API in Node.js. I've tried everything on the internet but nothing works. I'm new, so it must be a simple fix.

I think the API is the problem, but nothing works either side.

Here is the code to my custom built API

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;
const res = require("res");
const req = require("request");
const { createWorker} = require("tesseract.js");
const { text } = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const cors = require("cors");

const worker = createWorker();

app.use( express.json() )
app.use(cors({origin: true, credentials: true}));

app.get('/tes', (req,res) => {

    res.status(200).send({
        'tshirt':"ani",
    })
}) 

app.post('/h', (req, res, err) => {

    const { logo } = req.body;

    if(!logo) {
        res.status(418).send({ message: "We Need A Logo"})
    }

    
        async function nea() {
             await worker.load();
             await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
             await worker.initialize('eng');
             const text  = await worker.recognize(logo);
             var ret = text.data.text.replace('\n',' ');
             await console.log(ret);
             
             await res.send({
                "data":`${ret}`
             });
             await worker.terminate();
     } 

     }

);
app.listen(
    PORT,
    () => console.log(`open localhost`)
)
```

And the code to my app

```js
/*
            Code

     <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>    
        <Camera style={styles.container} ref={cameraRef} >
        </Camera>
        <Button title="Scan Doc" onPress={takePic} />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
*/
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, Button, Image } from 'react-native';
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { shareAsync } from 'expo-sharing';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import axios from 'axios';






export default function App() {
  let cameraRef = useRef();
  const [hasCameraPermission, setHasCameraPermission] = useState();
  const [hasMediaLibraryPermission, setHasMediaLibraryPermission] = useState();
  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const cameraPermission = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      const mediaLibraryPermission = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasCameraPermission(cameraPermission.status === "granted");
      setHasMediaLibraryPermission(mediaLibraryPermission.status === "granted");
    })();
  }, []);

  if (hasCameraPermission === undefined) {
    return <Text>Requesting permissions...</Text>
  } else if (!hasCameraPermission) {
    return <Text>Permission for camera not granted. Please change this in settings.</Text>
  }

  let takePic = async () => {
    let options = {
      quality: 1,
      base64: true,
      exif: false
    };

    let newPhoto = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(options);
    setPhoto(newPhoto);
  };

  if (photo) {
    let sharePic = () => {
      shareAsync(photo.uri).then(() => {
        setPhoto(undefined);
      });
    };
  
    let savePhoto = (err) => {

      MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(photo.uri).then(() => {
        fetch('http://192.168.1.12:5000/add', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    logo: "some-data"
  })
}).then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res));
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e.message)
    });

  };
   
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.preview} source={{ uri: "data:image/jpg;base64," + photo.base64 }} />
        <Button title="Share" onPress={sharePic} />
        {hasMediaLibraryPermission ? <Button title="Save" onPress={savePhoto} /> : undefined}
        <Button title="Discard" onPress={() => setPhoto(undefined)} />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
    };


  function DetailsScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  
    
    function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>                                                           
      <Camera style={styles.container} ref={cameraRef} >   
      </Camera>
      <Button title="Scan Doc" onPress={takePic} />
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    <StatusBar style="auto" />
  </View> 
    );
    };


  
  
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

    

   return (   
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
   ); 

   };   
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: 1000,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flex: 2,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  preview: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    flex: 1
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});
```

Can somebody please help? I've spent the last 10 days trying to solve it.

Comment: Your React code doesn't hit any of the express endpoints afaict. Also your server is running on port 8080, and the only endpoint your React _is_ hitting is one on port 5000. In other words it's not clear how your server/client code currently fits together.

Comment: I don't have any answers just observations. Your React code isn't fetching anything from `/tes` or `/h` which are the only endpoints in your Express server.

Comment: I forgot to edit the code, earlier the URL for fetch was "http://localhost:8080/h"

Comment: I tried creating project and backend works fine. however, the expo code simply doesn't run

Comment: [A small note on React Expo](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-expo-is-fooling-everyone-adf7f34d7528?gi=c5dc1a64e5a6)

Comment: Um Ohzan can u show me where the expo code doesn't run

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).